# How can I map a servlet for form to find it after submitting?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a form in my `login.jsp` like this:

```
<form action="LoginServlet" autocomplete="off" method="get">
    <p2>Login</p2>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

And when I submit it URL changes to *http://localhost:8080/LoginServlet?username=&password=* as it should (because I didn't put any input) but I get this error on the page:

> Whitelabel Error Page
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
> this as a fallback.
>
> Fri Jan 28 12:27:19 CET 2022 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
> Found, status=404).

The `LoginServlet` looks like this:

```
@WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)  throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("here");
    }
}
```

I think it has something to do with mapping(?). In my `IndexController.java` I have something like this to use URLs without .jsp extension:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(){
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String register(){
        return "register";
    }

}
```

What can I do to make sure that submitting the `form` will lead to the `LoginServlet`? Here's how my project's structure looks:
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YY1v.png)

Comment: You need to add your web app's context path to  your form's action. Right now the server is looking in the ROOT web app.

Comment: you're missing doPost/doGet function in your servlet. Also login functionality like this should be done with post not get - because otherwise it's not as secure.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to add your web app's context path to your form's action.
> Right now the server is looking in the ROOT web app.

`<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/LoginServlet" autocomplete="off" method="get">`